# How to pull out IPs from XML file?

Tags: xml, bash, xpath, grep, xml-parsing

I need to pull the IPs from XML data file. The problem is the `<![CDATA[]><br>`.

Structure of the file:

```
<IP><![CDATA[1.1.1.1]]></IP>
```

I have tried different ways to do it but still I cannot pull those IPs. Below some examples:

```
grep -oP '(?<=<IP><![CDATA[).*?(?=]></IP>)' test.xml
```

It doesn't work with CDATA tag. I have tried this:

```
awk -F'[<[]>]' '/<IP><![CDATA[/ { print}/]]/' test.xml
```

This one does not work either. Also tried:

```
xpath test.xml //IP/![CDATA[/text
```

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `xpath -q -e "//IP/text()" file.xml`

Answer (score 1):

XPath is a most natural way to handle XML. XPath knows how to handle CDATA sections.

Here is a correct XPath.

```
/IP/text()
```

Or

```
string(/IP/text())
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work. First it shows an syntax error because of the "()" and other thing is that it will show me the result with ![CDATA[1.1.1.1]]

Comment: @Charle, I shared a screen shot of the output.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only the IPs (and it's IPv4 only) and you have a grep version with extended regular expressions enabled than

```
grep -oE '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}' text.xml
```

should do.

Comment: Thank you. that's work for me. I forgot about that regex expression.